# Infinite prime product equals $\sqrt{5}$

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-product

If $p$ runs through the primes of form $20k+3$ and $20k+7$ and $q$ runs through the primes of form $20k+13$ and $20k+17$, then
$$\prod\limits^{\infty}\frac{p+1}{p-1}\prod\limits^{\infty}\frac{q-1}{q+1}=\sqrt{5}$$
How can I prove it?

Comment: where did you get this??

Comment: Surely neither of these products can converge on its own, because $\prod\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ doesn't converge. How are you pairing terms?

Comment: Anybody checked this out computationally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The product

$$P(s)=\prod_{p\equiv3,7\bmod{20}}\frac{p^s+1}{p^{s}-1}
\prod_{p\equiv13,17\bmod{20}}\frac{p^s-1}{p^{s}+1}$$

can be written, for $\Re(s)>1$, as a quotient of two Dirichlet $L$-series:

$$P(s)=\frac{L(s,\chi_1)}{L(s,\chi_2)}$$

where $\chi_1(k+20\mathbf Z)=-1$ iff $k=11,13,17,19$ and $\chi_1(k+20\mathbf Z)=1$ otherwise, and $\chi_2(k+20\mathbf Z)=-1$ iff $k=3,7,11,19$ and $\chi_2(k+20\mathbf Z)=1$ otherwise (of course, when $(k,n)>1$, both are zero). For $s=1$ it can be shown that

$$\frac{\overbrace{L(1,\chi_1)}^{\pi/\sqrt5}}{\underbrace{L(1,\chi_2)}_{\pi/5}}=\sqrt5$$

(the calculations are cumbersome, I've used Mathematica). Thus, we might expect the equality

$$P(1)"="\sqrt 5$$

but we are not allowed to do that, since the equality is valid only on the half-plane $\Re(s)>1$. Maybe someone can justify this last step, by rearranging the product in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  mentioned that the product diverge. I'm not sure but does it mean that we can't justify the last equality? so this is the best answer we can have.

Comment: @Yanko Yes, that was what I though, but numerically it seems that if you compute both products for primes $p\leq x$, and then take the limit $x\to\infty$, the result is $\sqrt5$

Comment: Thus, if the product is interpreted in an "appropriate manner", the equality might be true

Answer (score 3):

As i started the answer, the quick, compact and good answer (+1 from me) of iqcd was not here, so i switched to an editor, but typing killed me. The answer was here in between, same and only possible idea, will post it, since some details may bring a new information.

Let $T$ be the group of units of the ring $\Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z$. It has $\phi(20)=20\cdot\left(1-\frac 12\right)\left(1-\frac 15\right)=8$ elements, and it is isomorphic to...
$$ T\cong(\Bbb Z/4)\times(\Bbb Z/2)\ .$$

For the sake of typography, i will use [sage](http://www.sagemath.org) to have a quick information, here and in the sequel.

```
sage: R = ZZ.quotient(20)
sage: R
Ring of integers modulo 20
sage: G = R.unit_group()
sage: G.order()
8
sage: G
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C2 x C4
```

As generators, we take $11$, with $11^2=121=1$ (in $T$), and $17$, with powers $1,17,(28)9, (49)13$ (in $T$).

The characters are as in the following listing:

```
sage: D = DirichletGroup(20)
sage: for chi in D:
....:     print chi
....:     
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 1 mapping 11 |--> 1, 17 |--> 1
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 4 mapping 11 |--> -1, 17 |--> 1
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 5 mapping 11 |--> 1, 17 |--> zeta4
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 20 mapping 11 |--> -1, 17 |--> zeta4
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 5 mapping 11 |--> 1, 17 |--> -1
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 20 mapping 11 |--> -1, 17 |--> -1
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 5 mapping 11 |--> 1, 17 |--> -zeta4
Dirichlet character modulo 20 of conductor 20 mapping 11 |--> -1, 17 |--> -zeta4
```

and we want to see the characters from above, calculated at all places.

Here they are. Code:

```
D = DirichletGroup(20)
V = ( 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19 )
for v in V:
    print "%6s" % v,
print 

for chi in D:
    for v in V:
        print "%6s" % chi(v),
    print
```

Results:

```
 1      3      7      9     11     13     17     19
 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
 1     -1     -1      1     -1      1      1     -1
 1 -zeta4  zeta4     -1      1 -zeta4  zeta4     -1
 1  zeta4 -zeta4     -1     -1 -zeta4  zeta4      1
 1     -1     -1      1      1     -1     -1      1
 1      1      1      1     -1     -1     -1     -1
 1  zeta4 -zeta4     -1      1  zeta4 -zeta4     -1
 1 -zeta4  zeta4     -1     -1  zeta4 -zeta4      1
```

We will now type only the two lines that are mostly closed to the given problem:

```
 1      3      7      9     11     13     17     19
 1     -1     -1      1     -1      1      1     -1
 1      1      1      1     -1     -1     -1     -1
```

and the connection to the problem is as follows.
Consider the Dirichlet $L$-series associated to a Dirichlet character of $\Bbb Z/20$, in usual notation $\chi$, 
[Dirichlet $L$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function)
by 
$$
L(s,\chi)
=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac {\chi(n)}{n^s}
=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\ .
$$
The above Euler product is the one we are interested in.

The quotient of the two $L$-functions, associated to the two characters above is the value.

In our case, **formally**:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\prod_{\substack{p\equiv 3,7[20]\\p\text{ prime}}}\frac {p+1}{p-1}
\prod_{\substack{q\equiv 13,17[20]\\q\text{ prime}}}\frac {q-1}{q+1}
\\
&\qquad=
\prod_{\substack{p\equiv 3,7[20]\\p\text{ prime}}}\frac {1+\frac 1p}{1-\frac 1p}
\prod_{\substack{q\equiv 13,17[20]\\q\text{ prime}}}\frac {1-\frac 1q}{1+\frac 1q}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac
{\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi_1(p)}{p}\right)}
{\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi_2(p)}{p}\right)}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac
{\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi_2(p)}{p}\right)^{-1}}
{\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi_1(p)}{p}\right)^{-1}}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac
{L(\chi_2,1)}
{L(\chi_1,1)}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac
{\pi/\sqrt 5}
{\pi/5}
=\sqrt 5
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
With the "obvious" choices for $\chi_1,\chi_2$ from the above table.
Here, 
$$
L(1,\chi)
=
\frac {\pi i}{20}
\sum_{1\le a\le 9}\chi(a)\frac {\zeta^a+1}{\zeta^a-1}\ ,
$$
where $\zeta$ is the primitive root of order $20$, $\zeta=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{20}$. In our cases, we have used above:

```
sage: def L(chi):    return pi*i/20* sum( [chi(a) * (z^a+1)/(z^a-1) for a in [1..9]] )
sage: L( G.list()[1] ).simplify_full()
1/5*pi
sage: L( G.list()[5] ).simplify_full()
1/5*sqrt(5)*pi
```

(Sage was used again.)

**Note:**
There are some issues on convergence.

The right hand side of 
$$
L(s,\chi)
=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac {\chi(n)}{n^s}
%=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac {\chi(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1}
$$
is absolutely convergent for $s$ with real part $>1$, and convergent for  a non-trivial character, as in our cases, for $s$ with real part $>0$.

This is still not enough for using it, its partial sums, instead of partial Euler products in the **formal** computation above. The truncation of the products have to be controlled somehow. (I will try to look closer...)